# I want to make a progress-bar in HTML/CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am trying to create a progress arrow-bar which looks like similar to the image above. I started with a bar of bootstrap columns and do not know where to go from there.

My code looks like this so far:

```
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-10">

                                <div class="col-md-3" id="filter-1">
                                    <div class="panel-body" id="no-padding">

                                            Filter 1 

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3" id="filter-2">
                                    <div class="panel-body" id="no-padding">

                                            Filter 2

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3" id="filter-3">
                                    <div class="panel-body" id="no-padding">

                                            Filter 3

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1" id="filter-4">
                                    <div class="panel-body" id="no-padding">

                                            Filter 4

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>



                            <div class="col-md-1" id="filter-1">
                                <div class="panel-body" id="no-padding">

                                    Filter 5

                                </div>
```

Right now it looks like this
[image]

I am not sure how to make the shape like the image and apply a background-color change when it's clicked. I can handle the filtering effect, but I need help with the styling of the bar. Please help! Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+border+arrows

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. I know how to make an arrow, but I am not sure how to make it overlap with other bars and make it look like the image that I attached.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+progress+bar+arrow, first hit https://codepen.io/polinovskyi/pen/embZmw, a near-perfect example, second hit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744063/responsive-arrow-progress-bar-with-transparent-borders even a little more in-depth.